# If multiple classes contain same code for error checking should I extract it into new class?

Tags: java

I'm working on a project where several classes have the same error checking in one of their methods. Should I extract this error checking into a different class, even though it's only under 10 lines of code?

As an example, the method in all the classes take in the same object and does something different with it, I'm checking initially if that object is null and then getting a list from the object to see if it's empty. I was thinking of extracting these checks because I've heard each method should only do one thing.

Comment: You'd always share the code rather than explain it, it's so more clear to see the code that reading what it does ;)

Comment: Yes, sounds like a great idea.  It's perfectly OK to have very small classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule of thumb, you should always extract identical functionality in your codebase and reuse them instead of copying & pasting over. If you have to change the validation logic you'll have to do a [shotgun surgery](https://refactoring.guru/smells/shotgun-surgery) if it is appearing in multiple methods.

There are some battle-tested open-source libraries available for null checking and determining if collections are empty. Look around before implementing your own. Here is an [example](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Strings.html#isNullOrEmpty-java.lang.String-) from the Guava library.